# How to add multiple babelTransformerPath in metro.config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to use multiple `babelTransformerPath` in metro.config for react native app.

`react-native-svg-transformer` for SVGs and `react-native-obfuscating-transformer` for obfuscation.

React-Native - 0.64.0

React - 17.0.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved it by using `mergeConfig(configA, configB)`.

`metro.config.js` look like

```html
const {getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig } = require('metro-config');

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: {sourceExts, assetExts},
  } = await getDefaultConfig();

  let config1 = {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
      getTransformOptions: async () => ({
        transform: {
          experimentalImportSupport: false,
          inlineRequires: false,
        },
      }),
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg'],
    },
  };


  let config2 = {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("./transformer"), // react-native-obfuscating-transformer
      getTransformOptions: async () => ({
        transform: {
          experimentalImportSupport: false,
          inlineRequires: false,
        },
      }),
    },
  };

  return mergeConfig(config1,config2);
  
})();
```

Thanks to [Metro Docs](https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration/#merging-configurations)

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1:

we can check if file extension is `svg` or not if `svg` then we can use `svg` otherwise we can use `react-native-obfuscating-transformer`

**metro.config.js**

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('metro-config');

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts },
  } = await getDefaultConfig();

  return {
    transformer: {
      getTransformOptions: async () => ({
        transform: {
          experimentalImportSupport: false,
          inlineRequires: false,
        },
      }),
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('./transformer'),
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== 'svg'),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg'],
    },
  };
})();
```

**transformer.js**

```
const typescriptTransformer = require('react-native-typescript-transformer');
const obfuscatingTransformer = require('react-native-obfuscating-transformer-fix');
const svgTransformer = require('react-native-svg-transformer');

const filter = (filename) => {
  return filename.startsWith('src');
};

const obfuscating = obfuscatingTransformer({
  upstreamTransformer: typescriptTransformer,
  obfuscatorOptions: {
    compact: true,
    controlFlowFlattening: false,
    deadCodeInjection: false,
    debugProtection: false,
    debugProtectionInterval: false,
    disableConsoleOutput: true,
    identifierNamesGenerator: 'hexadecimal',
    log: false,
    renameGlobals: false,
    rotateStringArray: true,
    selfDefending: true,
    shuffleStringArray: true,
    splitStrings: false,
    stringArray: true,
    stringArrayEncoding: ['base64'],
    stringArrayThreshold: 0.75,
    unicodeEscapeSequence: false,
  },
  emitObfuscatedFiles: false,
  enableInDevelopment: true,
  filter: filter,
  trace: true,
});

module.exports.transform = function ({ src, filename, options }) {
  if (filename.endsWith('.svg')) {
    return svgTransformer.transform({ src, filename, options });
  } else {
    return obfuscating.transform({ src, filename, options });
  }
};
```

## Solution 2:

we can fix it by merging two configs like this `mergeConfig(config1, config2)`

**metro.config.js**

```
const { getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig } = require('metro-config');

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts },
  } = await getDefaultConfig();

  const config1 = {
    transformer: {
      getTransformOptions: async () => ({
        transform: {
          experimentalImportSupport: false,
          inlineRequires: false,
        },
      }),
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== 'svg'),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg'],
    },
  };

  const config2 = {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('./transformer'),
      getTransformOptions: async () => ({
        transform: {
          experimentalImportSupport: false,
          inlineRequires: false,
        },
      }),
    },
  };

  return mergeConfig(config1, config2);
})();
```